# Get shipping tax percentage from order object

Tags: magento2, shipping, tax-rates

How can I get the shipping tax percentage from order object. I can see the shipping rate column in sales_order table but I couldn't find the percentage of shipping tax. Please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From sales order You will get tax applied on shipping  with **shipping_tax_amount** tax percent will be available in item level . You can check the same in sales_order_item table  and the variable is **tax_percent** with this you can get the tax percent

Comment: Did you get solution @VIPIN?